# Tile Texture If Dimensions of Sprite Are Larger Than Texture

Tags: libgdx

I have a sprite that acts as a wall in a game that I am building. I would like to have the brick texture repeat itself instead of stretch to fit the height of the screen. I tried:

```
    Texture lSideTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("wall.png"));
    lSideTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);

    lSideSprite = new Sprite(lSideTexture);
    lSideSprite.setPosition(-50, -100 * (height/width) / 2);
    lSideSprite.setSize(5,100 * (height/width));
```

But I am still getting a texture that has been stretched to fit the dimensions rather than repeated.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to change the texture region of the Sprite to be bigger than the texture. So if you are drawing the sprite 5 times bigger than normal, you'd do this:

```
lsideSprite.setRegion(0, 0, 5f, 5f);
```

One "gotcha" here is that this method is overloaded to take all ints or all floats. If you use ints, then you specify the size in pixel dimensions. If you use floats, then you're specifying how many times you want it to repeat.

Comment: How am I to know how many times larger I am drawing the sprite? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You're the one designing the game...you draw it however big you want it and set the region to whatever size results in the scale you want.